# I Lost filter data with mvc paging while i filtered with viewmodel not text

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my controller:

```cs
public ActionResult Index(ServiceRequestViewModel modelSearch, int? ServiesRequestIDByRadiobtn, int? Page)
{
    ViewBag.modelreqtype = modelSearch;
    var ModelQuery = from a in _db.V_Service_Request_List
                        where ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelSearch.ServiceRequestNumber) ? true : a.ServiceRequestNumber.Contains(modelSearch.ServiceRequestNumber)) &&
                                (!modelSearch.RequestTypeCode.HasValue ? true : a.RequestTypeCode == modelSearch.RequestTypeCode) &&
                                (!modelSearch.RequestSubTypeCode.HasValue ? true : a.RequestSubTypeCode == modelSearch.RequestSubTypeCode) &&
                                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelSearch.PlantName) ? true : a.PlantNameAR.Contains(modelSearch.PlantName) || a.PlantNameEn.Contains(modelSearch.PlantName)) &&
                                (!modelSearch.RegionId.HasValue ? true : a.RegionId == modelSearch.RegionId) &&
                                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelSearch.IndustryLicenseNumber) ? true : a.IndustryLicenseNumber.Contains(modelSearch.IndustryLicenseNumber)) &&
                                (!modelSearch.StatusCode.HasValue ? true : a.StatusCode.Value == modelSearch.StatusCode) &&
                                (!modelSearch.ServiceRequestFromDate.HasValue ? true : a.ServiceRequestCreatedDate >= modelSearch.ServiceRequestFromDate) &&
                                (!modelSearch.ServiceRequestToDate.HasValue ? true : a.ServiceRequestCreatedDate <= modelSearch.ServiceRequestToDate))
                        select a;
    
    int RequestTypesCode = GetRequestTypesIDFromUserRole();

    var assignedTasks = (from a in DB.V_Service_Request_List
                            where a.AssigneeId == CurrentUserId
                            select a).ToList();

    //----------------------- Get Evaluator data For DRP------------------------------------------------
    ViewBag.EvaluatorsModel = GetEvaluatorsData();
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    var model = new ServiceRequestViewModel()
    {
        Regions = _db.Regions.ToList(),  //---المنطقة
        List_RequestSubTypes = modelSearch.RequestTypeCode.HasValue ? _db.Request_Sub_Type.Where(a => modelSearch.RequestTypeCode.HasValue ? a.request_type_code == modelSearch.RequestTypeCode : true).ToList() : new List<Request_Sub_Type>(), // نوع الاجراء
        List_RequestTypeStatuses = modelSearch.RequestTypeCode.HasValue ? _db.Request_Type_Status.Where(a => modelSearch.RequestTypeCode.HasValue ? a.request_type_code == modelSearch.RequestTypeCode : true).ToList() : new List<Request_Type_Status>(),
        //var userlist = _db.AspNetUsers.Where(a => a.AspNetRoles.Any(x => btnlist.Contains(x.Id)));
    };

    model.List_ServiceRequestTable = model.List_ServiceRequestTable.Where(x => x.StatusCode != IL_Draft)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ServiceRequestCreatedDate).ToPagedList(Pagenumber, PageSize);
    return View(model);
}
```

and HTML like this:

```html
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { modelSearch = ViewBag.modelSearch, page }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with myself :
and I did that in my controller to save my filter data with server-side paging

```
   public ActionResult Index(ServiceRequestViewModel modelSearch, int? ServiesRequestIDByRadiobtn, int? Page)
    {

        #region Pagination Conditions
        var TestModel = modelSearch;
        if (modelSearch.RequestTypeCode != null|| modelSearch.IndustryLicenseNumber != null || modelSearch.PlantName != null || modelSearch.RegionId != null || modelSearch.RequestSubTypeCode != null || modelSearch.ServiceRequestFromDate != null || modelSearch.ServiceRequestNumber != null || modelSearch.ServiceRequestToDate != null || modelSearch.StatusCode != null)
        {
            TempData["modelSearch"] = modelSearch;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Page != null)
            {
                TestModel = (ServiceRequestViewModel)TempData["modelSearch"];
                TempData["modelSearch"] = TestModel;
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["modelSearch"] = null;
            }

        }
        if (TestModel != null)
        {
            modelSearch = TestModel;
        } 
        #endregion

        var ModelQuery = from a in _db.V_Service_Request_List
                         where ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelSearch.ServiceRequestNumber) ? true : a.ServiceRequestNumber.Contains(modelSearch.ServiceRequestNumber)) &&
                                 (!modelSearch.RequestTypeCode.HasValue ? true : a.RequestTypeCode == modelSearch.RequestTypeCode) &&
                                 (!modelSearch.RequestSubTypeCode.HasValue ? true : a.RequestSubTypeCode == modelSearch.RequestSubTypeCode) &&
                                 (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelSearch.PlantName) ? true : a.PlantNameAR.Contains(modelSearch.PlantName) || a.PlantNameEn.Contains(modelSearch.PlantName)) &&
                                 (!modelSearch.RegionId.HasValue ? true : a.RegionId == modelSearch.RegionId) &&
                                 (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelSearch.IndustryLicenseNumber) ? true : a.IndustryLicenseNumber.Contains(modelSearch.IndustryLicenseNumber)) &&
                                 (!modelSearch.StatusCode.HasValue ? true : a.StatusCode.Value == modelSearch.StatusCode) &&
                                 (!modelSearch.ServiceRequestFromDate.HasValue ? true : a.ServiceRequestCreatedDate >= modelSearch.ServiceRequestFromDate) &&
                                 (!modelSearch.ServiceRequestToDate.HasValue ? true : a.ServiceRequestCreatedDate <= modelSearch.ServiceRequestToDate))
                         select a;


        int RequestTypesCode = GetRequestTypesIDFromUserRole();


        var assignedTasks = (from a in DB.V_Service_Request_List
                             where a.AssigneeId == CurrentUserId
                             select a).ToList();
```